# Sass: Outsourcing style into mixin does not work

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

So I am very new to Sass and have this strange behavior.

I want to create a checkbox that has different border colors when enabled and when disabled.

It looks like this.

Enabled:

[image]

Disabled:

[image]

So far, so good.

React-piece of code:

```
            <div className="item">
                <input type="checkbox" disabled={true} checked={true}/>
            </div>
```

And the (working) CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

// "before" works with mixin
input[type=checkbox]:before {
  @include checkbox_before;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

// "before" works with mixin
input[type=checkbox]:disabled:before  {
  @include checkbox_before;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

// ToDo: include mixin like for "before"
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 6px;
}

// ToDo: include mixin like for "before"
input[type=checkbox]:disabled:checked:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 6px;
}
```

Please notice the "ToDo: include mixin like for "before"". For "after", the mixin (`@include checkbox_before`) works fine.

But when I try the same for "before", it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  @include checkbox_after;
  border: solid #666666;
}

input[type=checkbox]:disabled:checked:after {
  @include checkbox_after;
  border: solid red;
}
```

... and the mixin:

```
// "before" section --> works
@mixin checkbox_before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

// "after" section --> does not work
@mixin checkbox_after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 6px;
}
```

As you can see, I put all the stylings in the mixin "`checkbox_after`" since they are all the same for enabled and disabled variation. The only thing that differs is the color.

So why does it work when I put all the stylings in the "big" CSS and not when I outsource them into the mixin? I can't find any explanation for that.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, so in cases someone else struggling with the problem:

Use a parameter for the mixin. So instead of including the mixin and declare the border extra, pass it as parameter to the mixin function like this:

```
@include checkbox_after(solid red);
```

The mixin then looks like this:

```
@mixin checkbox_after($border) {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: $border;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 6px;
}
```

Cheers!